# Understanding complexity of JavaScript algorithm using object as a hash

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to solve the following problem.

Given an array of ids

```
var ids = [8098272281362432, 7824519999782912];
```

Find all the matches in an array of items.

```
var people = [
    {
      "id": 8098272281362432,
      "age": 59,
      "name": "Douglas Hunter"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 625873891885056,
      "age": 1,
      "name": "Lottie Owen"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 7824519999782912,
      "age": 100,
      "name": "Maud Wise"
    }, 
    {
      "id": 2561552265773056,
      "age": 115,
      "name": "Annie Bennett"
    }
];
```

**Approach 1**
I could solve this by sorting both arrays by `id` (`O(n log n)`) and then iterating through both arrays once from the top down (`O(n)`)

```
var alg1 = function(people, ids) {
  var matches = [];

  var sortedPeople = people.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a.id - b.id
  });
  var sortedIds = ids.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  });
  var curPersonIndex = 0;

  sortedIds.forEach(function(id) {
    while (sortedPeople[curPersonIndex].id !== id) {
      curPersonIndex++;
    }

    matches.push(sortedPeople[curPersonIndex]);
  });

  return matches;
};
```

**Approach 2**
I though I could improve this with an `O(n)` algorithm by creating a mapping of ids to people and then I can just lookup the person for each id.

```
var alg2 = function(people, ids) {
  var matches = [];

  peopleMap = {};

  people.forEach(function(person) {
    //Is this O(1) or O(log n)?
    peopleMap[person.id] = person;
  });

  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    matches.push(peopleMap[id]);
  });

  return matches;
};
```

However when I test this out both algorithms seem to preform about the same. **#1** is faster in chrome and **#2** is slightly faster in Firefox.

http://plnkr.co/edit/FidAdBqS98RKebxaIlva?p=preview

I'm getting the feeling that inserting a field into an object is `O(log n)` not `O(1)` as I would have expected. I've read some conflicting posts on this though so I'm not sure. And I guess it may depend on the browser. Is there any way to consistently solve this with an O(n) algorithm in JavaScript?

Comment: If you have working code and want it improved, I wonder if http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be the best place for you post.

Comment: Taking the extra time to construct the `peopleMap` will likely pay off more for large data sets or if you create the map once and then do repeated lookups.  Also, it doesn't seem like you're taking advantage of the sorted arrays in #1 so I'm wondering why you even bothered to sort them.

Comment: are the arrays updated frequently or just once ?

Comment: @VikramBhat the arrays are just updated once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all JavaScript does not require that objects be implemented as hashes (average `O(1)` lookup) rather than using some other structure like a BTree that is `O(log(n))`.  So nobody can guarantee the performance of object attribute lookup.

But usually people use hashes.  Which are `O(1)`.

But as the joke says, *For all intents and purposes, log(n) is a constant.  For Google, it is a slightly larger constant.*  That captures a real truth.  The difference between `log(1000)` and `log(1000000000)` is a factor of 3.  The difference between accessing something in a CPU cache versus going to RAM is a factor of 10.  While in theory `O(1)` is better than `O(log(n))`, in practice with the sizes of data that we actually are likely to encounter, implementation details make a far larger difference.  And either can win.

So your benchmarks say nothing useful about the theoretical scaling rules.  And the fact that different implementations have different performance winners for your use case is one of the unfortunate facts about the world you have to work in.

Comment: I tested this with 2 million items. `Log2(2000000) = 21` So if Aproach 1 is `O(n log n)` and approach 2 is `O(n)` then I would have expected to see the `log n` start to have some effect. But both algorithms were still pretty much the same. So I think this may be more of a case of inserting into an object costing `O(log n)` rather than `log n` being too small to notice. But I guess it's still hard to say as other factors like CPU caching could be getting in the way

Comment: You really can't throw enough data at it to experimentally figure out what log factors there are.  Furthermore hashes tend to be hard on caches while sorting algorithms are very kind.  As an extreme example, if you've got 100 GB of data on disk, sort will out perform hashing by many orders of magnitude.